# How to mark conversation or message to be unread in a messaging app using ios7 and parse.com?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, messaging

I am building a messaging application for iPhone using Parse as my backend. How can I mark the conversation in the inbox view (not the message view) as there are unread messages here? But I want this the receiver to see it and not the sender... Since push notifications aren't always reliable, I want to find a way to let the user know there is an unread message in some conversation thread.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have two classes, one is conversation class which holds an array that points to the messages which reside in messages class. This set up was thankfully suggested by a StackOverflow member a while back.

I have not tried any code to post here... I don't even know how this will work... I am trying to implement a way with my current setup to flag a conversation if it has new messages. I thought about adding a column which indicates new messages inside this thread and based on it I can probably change the cell color in the inbox which has this flag set but then again this will show for both sender and receiver... I want it to show for receiver only and since receiver could be multiple in this case, this is where I am having an issue... It seems like there has to be another class that keeps track of this unless something can be done with the current setup...

Comment: Already voted down and I don't know why! Lol... Okay I guess an admin can delete this question.

Comment: I'm guessing you got the down votes because you haven't shown what you have tried, or shown any code at all. You also haven't given any information about your schema.

Comment: I added an edit to explain your questions... Hopefully someone can give me an insight! Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your current schema looks something like this?

```
Conversation : class
- messages : Array<Message>
- participants : Array<_User>
Message : class
- body : String
```

In regards to tracking read count vs message count, you could do that with a counter, e.g.

```
Conversation : class
- messages : Array<Message>
- participants : Array<ConversationParticipant>
- messageCount : Number
ConversationParticipant : class
- readMessageCount : Number
- user : Pointer<_User>
Message : class
- body : String
- readBy : Array<_User>
```

The idea would be:

- user adding a message to a conversation:

  - add author to `readBy` array on message
  - increase `messageCount` on Conversation
  - increase `readMessageCount` on ConversationParticipant for author
  - add message to `messages` on Conversation
- user (recipient) reading a message:

  - increase `readMessageCount` on ConversationParticipant
  - add user to `readBy` array on message
- showing new message count on conversation:

  - compare `messageCount` on Conversation to `readMessageCount` on ConversationParticipant that matches the current user
- showing read/unread status per message

  - check if `readBy` contains pointer to the current user (don't need to `include()` them, just compare the ID on the pointer)

Much of this could be done in Cloud Code in beforeSave or afterSave.

Comment: Hello Timothy! Sorry I haven't replied... Been busy with work... I think I will do this as an update for the app? Is this a good idea? Or is this a feature should be there already? I hope modifying the backend later won't be a disaster lol. Your solution sounds fantastic and makes sense... I just need to sit down and implement it but I just haven't been able to find the time yet... I will implement it later and get back with you! I appreciate the time you took to answer my question.

Comment: @M5er you could write a scheduled job to do the initial change (you would probably want some way to take the app offline while it runs though, to be safe, probably take under 10 minutes to do it).

Comment: @TimothyWalters How would you go about getting all of the conversations that the user is in?

Comment: Is there any way to do it without backend updates? Can we do it at the device level?